# Sorting 3D bounding boxes according to distance from specific point

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, depth-buffer

Is there an efficient way to calculate the order of 3D bounding boxes according to their distance from a specific point?

I can't simply take the center point of the bounding box since there are often cases where the bounding boxes are rotated, so that the order would be wrong. The following:
[image: graphic]
would result in a wrong ordering of the bounding boxes if I just sort by the center point's distance.

I've looked into 3D Engines since they have to deal with such stuff. They apparently use Z buffering on surfaces but I don't know much about all this computer graphics stuff.

Can anybody point me in the right direction or help me out with a possible solution? Best in Python?

**EDIT**
I didn't give you all the information. To clarify:

- The BBs are 3D (The drawing is just a simplified birds-eye view)
- The BBs are disjoint
- The BBs can have different sizes
- The BBs I get are rotated (mostly around the z axis when assuming z gives the heigth of the BBs)
- I don't generate the BBs and cannot influence their position or rotation in the scene. Rotating or moving them is not an option.
- There can be about up to 10 000 objects in my scene (theoretically 360 degrees around the view point).
- Lets assume the BBs are somewhat transparent. I need to order them according to what an observer would see from the *view point* in the image. If I'd just use the distance from observer to the center point of my objects (what the rays in the image indicate) it would sort B before A which is wrong.
- I referred to Z buffering because the goal is somewhat similar to what I want to achieve. (I'm not a CG specialist, so you might forgive me if I made a wrong comparison)

I am aware that with a lot of coordinate comparisons, I could find out which object is in front. I was hoping that there is already a more sophisticated and better performing solution than brute-force to such a problem out there.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow!   You're describing a nice problem, but I've got a question:   What are you trying to do with the sorted order?   From your illustration and your reference to Z buffering, it seems like you're trying to determine display priority.

Comment: Every bounding box is composed of 8 vertices, so you could sort them using those. The Euclidean distance between two points can be determined by using the Pythagorean theorem that the [math.hypot()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function implements. The vertex closest to the specified point might be a good metric depending on how you're rendering the boxes.

Comment: I don't ever have to plot the boxes but calculate the occlusion for every object. The observer in the scene is a perception layer sensor, e.g. a Lidar. So, to determine what the Lidar actually sees, I thought that sorting the objects correctly and then calculating the occlusions based on the order of objects would be a good way to do it. I was hoping for a solution where I don't have to check so many vertices as I might have 10 000 objects in my scene.

Comment: A few more questions:   (1)  Are the BB's disjoint?   (2)  Why not use axis-aligned BB's?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by distance, in the picture you show, box B is closer to the View point along some rays but farther along others.

Z buffering is a per pixel operation, i.e. it is not sorting this closer to a view point, it is picking the closest point along a specific direciton *for every pixel*.

Comment: @MarkLavin (1) Yes, they are (I made some edit to clarify my problem a little more). (2) I just looked this up, if I understood correctly this would mean I have to rotate the bbs, right? I get the BBs from somewhere else, so their rotation in the room is fixed.

Comment: @Makogan Bad description on my side, sorry. I made some clarifications to the post. Yeah, I thought some adaption of z buffering might also help with my problem since some colleages pointed me in this direction. I'm not a CG pro unfortunately. I just thought that I can't be the first person to have this problem and that there must be an elegant (and efficient) way to solve this.

Comment: @flashback_6 I think you still do not understand what I am asking. There is not a single right answer to which box should come first in teh diagram you are showing. You claim that diagram is wrong, but wrong with respect to what?

What makes you think A should come before B? Notice that an observer is closer to either A or B depending on the line that we choose, moreover the closest point to the observer is in B not in A (the corner of B),  Think about what you are trying to accomplish and then describe it to us. Currently it's ahrd to answer you because there is no right answer.

Comment: I believe that since the BB's are convex and disjoint, you *can* define a partial ordering "occludes" between every pair.   It seems like a fairly complicated predicate to evaluate, lots of testing of point vs. face.   It *may* be helpful to first transform all the coordinates of the BB's into the 3D (yes, 3D) perspective space, ignoring any BB that has negative perspective depth.   I wonder, though, whether there's a sweep-plane algorithm to do the "pre-ordering".